# Rake on Rails 3 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I moved a Rails 2.3 application to Rails 3.
The application actually works perfectly, but I have issue with rake tasks.
It looks like the config in the environment file is not initialized correctly.
the error I get is:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `cache_classes=' for #<Hash:0x3c3e850>
/var/www/apps/nzar3/config/environments/development.rb:9
.....
```

The environment file is clean, and it works.
Here the environments/development.rb

```
config.cache_classes = false
config.whiny_nils = true
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
config.action_view.debug_rjs                         = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false
config.active_support.deprecation = :log
config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Rails3 uses a different syntax for configuration of your application.

```
YourApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false
end
```

Did you migrate your app by running `rails /path/to/rails2/app`?

Have a read of this good article for [tips about upgrading to Rails 3](http://omgbloglol.com/post/353978923/the-path-to-rails-3-approaching-the-upgrade).

Comment: yeah mate, I forgot that section
I have it in the congif file
Appxxx::Application.configure do ...

Comment: I created a brand new app rails 3 and migrated pieces

Comment: I mean, I already had the configuration correctly set up. I just didn't post here

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem also, it was related to the cache_fu plugin being installed.  Removing cache_fu made the issue go away.

Comment: mmm I just tried that, removed cache_fu, still having same issue. nevermind, I don't deploy this app that often, so screw it eheh

Answer (score 0):

Full config file

```
App::Application.configure do
 config.cache_classes = false
 config.whiny_nils = true
 config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
 config.action_view.debug_rjs                         = true
 config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false
 config.active_support.deprecation = :log
 config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it's only this rake task that uses ActionView doesn't work

```
namespace :cached_assets do
  desc "Regenerate aggregate/cached files"
  task :regenerate => :environment do
    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
    include ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
    stylesheet_link_tag :all, :cache => 'a'
    javascript_include_tag :defaults, :cache => 'b'
    javascript_include_tag "c.js", :cache => 'c'
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
 comment this portion

```
config.action_view.debug_rjs   = true
```

from `environments/development.rb`